# Размещение картинки поверх тега видео и запуск по ней звука

Tags: html, jquery, css

Подскажите как, разместить поверх видео в верхнем левом углу картинку, кликая по которой звук в видео запускался

```js
$(document).on("click","img.mute", function(){
    $(this).attr("muted", "");
})
```

```css
video {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
video img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video controls width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" muted>
    <img src="images/muted.svg" class="mute">
    <source src="images/work_where_convenient.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько ошибок:

1. `<img>` внутри `<video>` используется как плейсхолдер, когда видео не загружено. Т.е если видео играет, картинки внутри не видно.
2. Z-index видео выше чем у картинки
3. Используйте `prop()` вместо `attr()`

```js
$(document).on("click", "img.mute", function() {
  $('#testvideo').prop("muted", false);
})
```

```css
video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
img.mute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/63c031189b273375b936c20dcc579c6d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" class="mute">
<video id="testvideo" controls width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" muted>
  
  <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нахожу видео элемент через jquery, через [0] получаю прямой доступ к элементу в доме.
Дальше нахожу "кнопку", потом на кнопку накидываю эвент по клику.
При клике проверяю, если звук видео заглушен (проверяется свойством muted), то убираю мутед и меняю содержимое кнопки и наоборот.

```js
const video = $('video')[0];
const $control = $('.control');

$control.on('click', function() {
 if (video.muted) {
   video.muted = false;
    $control.text('Выкл звук');
  } else {
   video.muted = true;
    $control.text('Вкл звук');
  }
})
```

```css
.video-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}

.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-block">
  <div class="control">Вкл звук</div>
  <video controls poster="http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png" muted>
    <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video spec.
  </video>
</div>
```